# How should a Rebol-structured data file (which contains no code) be written and read?

Tags: reflection, rebol, rebol3

If you build up a block structure, convert it to a string with MOLD, and write it to a file like this:

```
>> write %datafile.dat mold [
    [{Release} 12-Dec-2012]
    [{Conference} [12-Jul-2013 .. 14-Jul-2013]]
]
```

You can LOAD it back in later.  But what about headers?  If a file contains code, it is supposed to start with a header like:

```
rebol [
    title: "Local Area Defringer"
    date: 1-Jun-1957
    file: %defringe.r
    purpose: {
        Stabilize the wide area ignition transcriber
        using a double ganged defringing algorithm.
    }
]
```

If you are just writing out data and reading it back in, are you expected to have a `rebol []` header, and extend it with any properties you want to add?  Should you come up with your own `myformat []` header concept with your own properties?

Also, given that LOAD does binding, does it make sense to use it for data or is there a different operation?

Comment: Note that you can combine the WRITE + MOLD steps into SAVE.

Comment: To avoid binding with LOAD, you can use `LOAD/type data 'unbound`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebol data doesn't *have* to have a header, but is best practice to include one (even if it's just data).

Some notes:

- `SAVE` is your best bet for serializing to `file!` or `port!` and has a mechanism for including a header.
- `MOLD` and `SAVE` both have an `/ALL` refinement that corresponds to `LOAD` (without `/ALL`, some data from `MOLD` and `SAVE` cannot be reliably recovered, including Object, Logic and None values).
- `LOAD` discards the header, though you can load it using the `/HEADER` refinement.

Putting this together:

```
save/all/header %datafile.dat reduce [next "some" 'data][
    title: "Some Data"
]

header: take data: load/header %datafile.dat
```

To use a header other than `Rebol []`, you'd need to devise a separate loader/saver.

Comment: If one is going to use the Rebol header, is there a convention to put custom fields unique to one's own data format?  Or should those be in a separate header after the Rebol header?

Comment: @HostileFork If it's valid metadata, I'd add it to the header. Only real snag is that you can't guarantee the custom field will be a word of a given header object, whereas you can always rely on the default set: Title, Name, Version, Date, File, Author, Needs, Options, Checksum.

Comment: Actually, that's not strictly true. You can append to the prototype header object at `SYSTEM/STANDARD/HEADER` and your custom field will be included in every subsequent loaded header whether it's included in the header or not.

Comment: I appreciate you mentioned save/all. Without it, there may be a problem with data like #[none], #[unset!], #[true], #[false]. However, it is not true that save without /all corresponds to DO. That is just a long said error.

Comment: @Ladislav fair point, it is not one to one. However, DO is closer to LOAD when recovering data from a plain SAVE that includes objects and none!/logic! literals. I appreciate this is not a reliable way to serialize data. Use /ALL.

Comment: SAVE also has the advantage of supporting compression, which LOAD seamlessly decompresses.

Answer (score 2):

For the case of reading, [**`construct`**](http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wconstruct.html) works very well alongside `load` to prevent evaluation (of code as opposed to data):

```
prefs: construct/with load %options.reb default-prefs
```

It is:

### Similar to `context`

```
obj: [
    name: "Fred" 
    age: 27 
    city: "Ukiah"
]

obj-context: context obj
obj-construct: construct obj
```

In this case, the same:

```
>> obj-context = obj-construct
== true
```

### Different

when it comes to evaluating code:

```
obj-eval: [
    name: uppercase "Fred" 
    age: 20 + 7 
    time: now/time
]

obj-eval-context: context obj-eval
obj-eval-construct: construct obj-eval
```

This time parsing differently:

```
>> obj-eval-context = obj-eval-construct
false

>> ?? obj-eval-construct
obj-eval-construct: make object! [
    name: 'uppercase
    age: 20
    time: now/time
]
```

---

#### Aside:

This is the point I realize the following code wasn't behaving as I expected:

```
obj-eval: [
    title: uppercase "Fred" 
    age: 20 + 7
    city: "Ukiah"
    time: now/time
]
```

gives in red (and by extension, rebol2):

```
>> obj-eval-construct: construct obj-eval
== make object! [
    title: 'uppercase
    age: 20
    city: "Ukiah"
    time: now/time
]
```

`lit-word!` and `lit-path!` is different.
TODO: question

---

It has also

## Useful refinement `/with`

Which can be used for defaults, similar to `make`